# Finding orthogonally similar diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

If $\ A = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 \end{bmatrix} $ and I want to find orthogonal matrix $\ P  , P^t A P = D $ where $\ D $ is diagonal matrix.

$p(A) = (t-3)(t-1) $ therefore $\ A $ has two egeinvalues $\ 3,1 $ and it is similar to the matrix $\ D = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 3 \end{bmatrix} $ so now I'm looking for orthogonal matrix and I know $\ A \sim \begin{bmatrix} -1 & 1 \\ 1 & - 1\end{bmatrix}$ how could I come up with orthogonal matrix $\ P $? I know that orthogonal matrix is $\ P^t P = P P^t = I $

Comment: What does $A\sim \begin{bmatrix} -1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1\end{bmatrix}$ mean?

Comment: symmetric. Yet I it multiplying it by A and then again it does not give me D.

Comment: The orthogonal matrix $P$ is related to eigenvectors of $A$.

Comment: I'm not sure what does it mean that $\ P $ is related to eigenvecotrs $\ A $ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say your eigenvalues are $t_1 = 1, t_2 = 3 $.  to find an orthogonal matrix in general you can simply find some associated eigenvectors and perform the [Gram-Schmidt Process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) to generate an orthonormal basis for the column space of $A$ (when $A$ is much much larger than a $2\times2$.)  This problem is relatively simple so I won't bother here:

First solve $$A_{t_1}x = \begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 1  \\ 1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}x_1 + x_2 \\ x_1 + x_2 \end{pmatrix}  = 0 $$

One solution is pretty obviously $u_1 = \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \right)^T$

Similarly solving 
$$A_{t_2}x = 0$$

$u_2 = \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \right)^T$

Notice that here each matrix $A_{t_i}$ is singular (i.e. $\det(A) = 0$).  This should always be the case, because we want $\{0\} \subsetneq \ker A_{t_{i}}$.  That is, we want a nontrivial solution to $(A - tI)x = 0$.  If the matrix is not non-singular you have made a mistake in finding the eigenvalues and should double check your work.

In Any case if you let $P = (u_1, u_2)$ will be as you desire.  In fact, this procedure will work in general for an $n \times n$ matrix.  The columns of $P$ will always correspond to the orthonormalized set of eigenvectors (note that order does very much matter here)

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy! yet when checking $\ \begin{pmatrix} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \end{pmatrix} \times \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 \end{pmatrix} \times \begin{pmatrix} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \end{pmatrix} \not = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 3 \end{pmatrix} $ even though $\ P $ is orthogonal according to defintion and I checked that I'm not wrong about the eigen values.

Comment: you have too many negatives in $P$.  Double check your statement of $P$ in comparison to mine.

Comment: That's because $\ ||u_1|| = \sqrt{2} \rightarrow \frac{u_1}{||u_1||} $ correct? And Thanks alot!!

Comment: yes, that's what it means for a vector to be unit length

Comment: You only need to use Gram-Schmidt or some equivalent process when there are repeated eigenvalues. Eigenvectors that correspond to different eigenvalues of a real symmetric matrix are always orthogonal. The only thing that really needs to be done to the eigenvectors here is to normalize them.